# Center App Bar title on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create my own custom app bar with a center-aligned title. Android Studio's editor shows my title is properly centered, but it is not on my actual device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.encounter_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.encounter_menu_bar_layout);
}
```

**encounter_menu_bar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/encounter_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/untitled"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**encounter_menu_bar.xml** doesn't have anything in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

</menu>
```

[image: Here's what shows up on my device]

**EDIT**

A lot of you are recommending that I change `android:layout_gravity` to `android:gravity`. I've tried that as well and I'm still not getting it to line up properly.

I'm enabling the app bar to show up on a specific fragment, as shown here:

**EncounterFragment.java**

```
public class EncounterFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_encounter, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.encounter_menu_bar, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO: This
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I also forgot to mention that I'm attaching the menu in a fragment. This is its layout:

**fragment_encounter.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/encounter_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:gravity="center"` in your textview

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding   `android:gravity="center"`.
This happens because you have to center the whole text and not just the layout

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Ok so try to change the <pre> "wrap_content"  <code> in <pre> android:layout_width="wrap_content" <code> and <pre> android:layout_height="wrap_content" <code> with <pre> "fill_parent"<code>

Comment: I changed `wrap_content` to `match_parent` for both width and height and it still looks the same

Comment: Well it's strange because "match_parent" means the text fills the layout while "wrap_context" the text occupy the space it needs...

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: `layout_gravity`, **not** `gravity`

In your case:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/encounter_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/untitled"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the textview to this

make it match parent for width, And make gravity center to center the text

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/encounter_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/untitled"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your xml view to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
#this should be horizontal, not vertical.
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/encounter_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/untitled"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

To start, you need to make your linear layout horizontal, not vertical. By making it vertical, you are aligning it to the left.

Then, you need to make sure that your `textview` width and height match the parent, rather than just wrap the  content. Then you can use the `gravity` attribute to make sure that the text is centered. When you used gravity before, the `textview` simply wrapped the content, and thus it didn't center in the textview. By matching the parent view bounds, you will be able to then center the text as you need to.

Comment: @cincospenguinos did you change your layout width & height to match parent?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I'm still not getting it to center though. I can't help but wonder if there is another option in another file I'm overlooking

Comment: There must be something else going on, because that is how you center the text inside a textview.

Comment: @cincospenguinos see my updated answer. You need to make a minor adjustment to your linear layout also :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It still is aligned on the left side, in spite of linear layout being oriented `horizontal`ly

Answer (score 0):

This is how your Toolbar XML should be

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
     />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in your Activity

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
 TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```